# Find XML node in d:-namespace in Java using XPath

Tags: java, xml, xpath, namespaces

I have an XML file of which I want to address a certain element in Java using an XPath. The problem is that the element is in the d:-namespace, and everything I have tried to add the namespace to the XPath according to the topics on this that I have found did not work. Is the d:-namespace a special namespace that follows different rules?

For reference, here is the XML I am trying to work with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xml:base="https://company.com/organisation/_api/"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"
    xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <entry m:etag="&quot;3&quot;">
        <id>067d7924-2a19-4094-b588-347b0869a19c</id>
        <content type="application/xml">
            <m:properties>
                <d:Modified m:type="Edm.DateTime">2023-10-06T11:02:47Z</d:Modified>
            </m:properties>
        </content>
    </entry>
    <entry m:etag="&quot;6&quot;">
        <id>c0a9aca5-2a1e-41e5-9da8-95fcd46d3109</id>
        <content type="application/xml">
            <m:properties>
                <d:Modified m:type="Edm.DateTime">2023-10-16T06:46:11Z</d:Modified>
            </m:properties>
        </content>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

Effectively, I am first getting a list of both entries as `XPathNodes` via the XPath `/feed/entry`, then iterate over them and trying to get the Modified dates via the XPath `//d:Modified`. In theory, that should work, but in practice, it always returns me an empty string.

I have tried the following for adding the namespace to the XPath, but without any success so far:

Option A (the answer I found on other threads):

```
        XPathFactory xf = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        xpath.setNamespaceContext(new NamespaceContext() {
            @Override
            public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
                if ("d".equals(prefix)) {
                    return "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices";
                }
                return null; // Return null for other prefixes
            }

            @Override
            public String getPrefix(String namespaceURI) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }

            @Override
            public Iterator<String> getPrefixes(String namespaceURI) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }
        });
```

Option B (something I tried myself):

```
        XPathFactory xf = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        SimpleNamespaceContext namespaceContext = new SimpleNamespaceContext();
        namespaceContext.bindNamespaceUri("d", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices");
        xPath = xf.newXPath();
        xPath.setNamespaceContext(namespaceContext);
```

Option C (if I do it like that, the code I use to get the entries no longer works and the XPathNodes contains 0 entries)

```
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
```

I have also tried accessing it via the XPath `//*[local-name()='Modified']`, but the problem with that is that even if I am already in one specific entry, it still returns to me the Modified nodes of *both* entries (which confused me at first until I realized that all nodes apparently still contain the entire document tree). If I try to access something inside the nodes such as the id (via `//id`), it works nicely and returns just that one correct node. It just doesn't work with anything in that weird d:-namespace, and I have no idea why.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

---

EDIT:

To clarify, my aim is to find all entries, iterate over them and get their "Modified" dates so I can work with that. In essence, this is how I imagine that should look like, but I tried and it doesn't work that way, forcing me to use the workaround with the node ID and the namespace breaking.

```
Node getMostRecentNode(){
    Document document = getDocument();
    XPathNodes entries = evaluteXpath(itemsDocument, "/feed/entry", XPathNodes.class);
    for (int index = 1; index < entries.size(); index++) {
        Node entry = entries.get(index);
        String modifiedString = evaluteXpath(entry, "//d:Modified", String.class);
        [...logic for getting most recent node ...]
    }
}
```

Is this something that could work if I got the namespaces right? Or do I already have an error in my understanding of how XPaths work at this stage?

Comment: I would rather think that you overlooked the default namespace declaration `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"` on the root element that is also in scope for `entry` to your attempt with `//entry` doesn't select anything as it selects `entry` elements in no namespace.

Comment: And of course the problem with `//*[local-name()='Modified']` is that it looks through the whole context document so you want `.//d:Modified` or `.//*[local-name() = 'Modified']`, if you prefer that hack.

Comment: @MartinHonnen : I tried adding the default namespace, but maybe I did it wrong. Can you maybe give me an example for how that would look in this case? This whole namespace thing is very confusing for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, I have now found something that works. I don't think it's ideal, but it *does* get the job done.

Basically, what I now do is rely on the fact that I can read the ID from a node once I have it, and then use that ID to build a complete XPath with the namespace-ignore-hack.

The whole mess looks somewhat like this:

```
public String getTargetNodeModified(XPathNodes entries) {
    Node targetEntry = getTargetNode(entries);
    String targetEntryId = evaluteXpath(latestEntry, "*", String.class);
    String searchString = String.format(
        "//entry[id='%s']//*[local-name()='Modified']",
        targetEntryId
    );
    return evaluteXpath(targetEntry, searchString, String.class);
}

public <T> T evaluteXpath(Object object, String xPathString, Class<T> type) {
    XPathExpression xPathExpression = xPath.compile(xPathString);
    return xPathExpression.evaluateExpression(object, type);
}
```

Again, I find it very funky that I need to add the `//entry[id='%s']` when I'm basing my search on the `targetEntry`, but apparently that's how it works.

If anyone can think of a cleaner solution for this mess, please post it here.

---

EDIT:

Thanks to one of @Michael Kay 's comments below, I was now able to simplify it to this:

```
public String getTargetNodeModified(XPathNodes entries) {
    Node targetEntry = getTargetNode(entries);
    return evaluteXpath(targetEntry, ".//*[local-name()='Modified']", String.class);
}
```

Comment: You should be able to use `String searchString =  ".//*[local-name()='Modified']";`

Comment: In fact, you should be able to use `String searchString =  ".//d:Modified";`

Comment: But I wouldn't expect `//entry` to select anything (because the element is in a namespace) and I certainly wouldn't expect `//entries` to select anything (because there's no such element). I suspect that in your frustration you are making little mistakes: try sleeping on it overnight.

Comment: @MichaelKay I made a mistake in the post, the XPath for getting the entries is `/feed/entry`, and that works just fine for getting all the entries. However, the `.//d:Modified` XPath always returns an empty result. Meanwhile, the XPath `".//*[local-name()='Modified']"` seems to work and eliminates the need to search out the entryId, so thanks for that! =^,^=

Answer (score -1):

I think your problem stems from not realizing that the namespace prefixes in the input document does not have to match the prefixes used in the XPath expression. As long as the prefixes resolves to the same Namespace URIs, everything should be ok. Here's an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Document doc = ....

    XPathFactory xpf = XPathFactory.newDefaultInstance();

    XPath xp = xpf.newXPath();
    xp.setNamespaceContext(new MyNamespaceContext());
    String template = "//a:entry[a:id='%s']//b:Modified";
    String expr = String.format(template, "c0a9aca5-2a1e-41e5-9da8-95fcd46d3109");
    Element m = (Element) xp.evaluate(expr, doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
    if (m != null) {
        System.out.println(m.getTextContent());
    }
}

static class MyNamespaceContext implements NamespaceContext {

    private final Map<String, String> mappings = Map.of(
            "a", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom",
            "b", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices",
            "c", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"
            );

    @Override
    public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
        return mappings.get(prefix);
    }
    
    // other methods returns null
}
```

Executing this against your sample prints:

```
2023-10-16T06:46:11Z
```

Comment: But that still does not eliminate the need for the ID. Ideally, what I want to search for is just `//d:Modified` as I iterate over the nodes. I'll edit my question to make this clear. I tried adjusting my code with the `MyNamespaceContext` and then search for `//b:Modified`, which did not find anything, and when I adjusted my iterator to use `/a:feed/a:entry` to search for the entries, it no longer found any entries at all.